# How to make carousel/slider/image switcher with fading effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I found many online slider libraries like the one here: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/flutter-carousel
But none of them supports fading effect between images (image transition between slides to be fading).

I found also an example of fading animated widgets in the documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html
and
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

I'm thinking about make placeholder widget and using a timer to switch between image using the suggested approach in the documentation. Is this the best approach to achieve that? Are there any other ready-made libraries or easier way to do it?

Answer (score 8):

You probably already solved this based on how long this had no answers, but today I had to help a friend with a problem similar to yours and came up with your same solution: using `AnimatedSwitcher` + `FadeTransition` + `Timer.periodic`. It's not a list of images in this example, but you can easily change the list to `List<String>` and also the widget to `Image.network` instead of `Icon`.

Here's the runnable solution + code: https://dartpad.dev/?id=c1332cc136c96fa5980c3e05c7faeb4b

Comment: Took me a long time to finally found a nice exemple ! Thank you !

Comment: @Gildásio Filho could you refresh link to the code?